# Listen to key events inside AngularJS partials

Tags: angularjs

I want to control arrow buttons in the partial with arrow keys.
I am listening to window's keyup in my controller for the partial.

Is there something wrong with the approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the approach, you can listen to window's keyup anyway, this has no link with using a partial or not.

You can use $document.bind('keyup'), see [documentation here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24document)

There is also a an angular-ui initiative : [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils#keypress)

Answer (score 0):

The Angular UI library had a module called Keypress, which is now part of their Utils module.
See here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

If you wish to use something outside the angular environment, Mousetrap is the most powerful and easy to use keyboard library I have found. See here http://craig.is/killing/mice